# User input within for loop in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, excel

Okay.  I NEARLY got it.  I'm having a looping issue.  I can't get the PHP side to sit still and wait for a user response.  I try isset and it still continues on.  I'm pasting my code here.  Hope that's ok.  The excel spreadsheet it's pulling from basically row=4 as your multiple choices, then you choose, it finds the column you chose and goes down a row to ask the next row of questions...  I'm sorry guys I know this is noob town but I really appreciate the feedback.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>
</title>
</head>

    <body>

    <?php

    // include class file
    include 'Excel/reader.php';

    // initialize reader object
    $excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

    // read spreadsheet data
    $excel->read('Question-Flow.xls');    

    $x = 4; //Row
    $y = 0; //Column @ 0 for 1st iteration

    $questions = array();  //Stores questions and ends in 'STOP'

    //Iterates down a row until $cell='SUBMIT'
    do {

            //Populates $questions() and iterates until $cell='STOP'
            do {

                $y++;

                $cell = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';

                if ($cell){

                    //Populates $questions array with active cells
                    array_push($questions, $cell);

                }

            } while ($cell != 'STOP');

          for ($i=0; $i < count($questions)-1; $i++){

                    //echo "<input type=radio name=$i value=\"".$questions[$i]."\">".$questions[$i]."<br>";
                    ?>
                <HTML><BODY>
                    <form action="index.php" method="post">
                    <input type=submit name=choice value=<?php echo $questions[$i]; ?> style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"><br>
                    </form>                
                    </BODY></html>
                <?php

                //Move $cell back one from 'STOP'
                $y--;
                $cell = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';

                $choice = $_POST['choice'];

                if(isset($_POST['choice'])){
                    echo $choice;
                    echo $cell;
                    echo $x;
                    echo $y;
                }
          }

            while($choice != $cell){

                //Iterate back to find $choice
                $y--;

                $cell = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';

            }

            //Moves to next row of Questions
            $x++;

            //Populates $cell with 'SUBMIT' or prompts next question
            $cell = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';

    } while ($cell != 'SUBMIT');

    ?>


    </body>
</html>
```

---

I am lost.  I'm new to PHP, javascript, HTML so please excuse the dumb question.  I've got this array that's been populated with strings from an excel file.  The print looks like

`Array ( [0] => Question1 [1] => Question2 [2] => Question3 [3] => STOP )`

I need to present the user each of those value's as a question and have them choose between them.  I then need to loop back around and input new values from excel (this is all done) into that array and come back asking them new questions.  I need to store their answer to feed into the excel loop which "cell" they chose.  It's like a branching tree of questions.

If I could put some type of input form into the below for loop that would work right? Won't take though.

```
  for ($i=0; $i < count($questions); $i++){
      echo $i;  //echo'd just to see the count and it's correct
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ashish, the relationship between a html form and a php file is built using script parameters. Creating the form on the spot is one step, but the form must send back the answers to a php script that can process the variables sent: in your case, the answers. After that, if all or part of the answers are stored in the parameters you sent to the php script you can copy them all using the for loop.

You need the form (generated by php or static html) with the POST method such as: http://w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_post

And a php script like the welcome demonstration here: http://w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

If you use the same script for form generation and for posting (making the field values equal to POST variables you received) it may look a little more interactive. For advanced behaviours you should at least go through w3schools.com brief course on php, html and after that, some javascript.

Comment: Please don't provide references from w3schools. The information there is often out of date or invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`foreach`** loop as follows

```
foreach($questions as $qst){
    echo "<input type=radio name=q1 value=\"".$qst."\">".$qst."<br>";
}
```

The user can select a question in terms of radio button.